# how to display list<> in drop down list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu

I have a dropdownlist where I want to display a list of users. To call the users I use `ChatUserDetails.GetPXPUsers()`

Which brings me to this code:

```
public static List<ChatUserDetails> GetPXPUsers()
        {
            List<ChatUserDetails> Users = new List<ChatUserDetails>();
            string SQL = SelectPXPUsers;

            DataTable dtMainItems = ChatUserDetails.CustomFill(SQL, null);

            foreach (DataRow dr in dtMainItems.Rows)
            {
                Users.Add(new ChatUserDetails(dr));
            }

            return Users;
        }
```

But how to I display this list of users in my dropdownlist?

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="DropDownListPXPUsers"></asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: DropDownListPXPUsers.DataSource=GetPXPUsers();

Comment: @RobertMcKee The dropdownlist is still empty. It is not showing the list of users

Comment: After this line `DropDownListPXPUsers.DataSource=GetPXPUsers();` you need to bind the data to the DropDown as `DropDownListPXPUsers.DataBind();`

Comment: Someone (@RobertMcKee or @Izzy) convert these comments to answer to help others in future. Comments may not be read always.

Comment: @nvartak Converted my comment into an answer as requested

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind your list to your drop down at runtime by using the following code. You will need to specify which properties of the object are to be used.

```
DropDownListPXPUsers.DataSource = GetPXPUsers();
DropDownListPXPUsers.DateTextField = "PropertyOne"; // name of 'ChatUserDetails' property
DropDownListPXPUsers.DataValueField = "PropertyTwo"; // name of 'ChatUserDetails' property
DropDownListPXPUsers.DataBind();
```

Read more: See Examples in the [DropDownList](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) documentation.

Answer (score 2):

First you'll need to set the `DataSource` for the `DropDownList` and then you will need to call `DataBind()`.

```
if(!IsPostBack)
{
  DropDownListPXPUsers.DataSource = GetPXPUsers();
  DropDownListPXPUsers.DataBind();
}
```